# Android app does not refresh after soft-keyboard is hidden

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

After entering text using android soft-keyboard and manually closing it using the key available below the keyboard, the app page is not getting refreshed. A black space is shown where the keyboard had existed.

I tried with various options available for windowSoftInputMode and it does not fix this issue. Sadly, adjustPan is not showing its expected behavior. The keyboard hides the text fields when the windowSoftInputMode is set to adjustPan.

How can I make the page refresh after the soft-keyboard is hidden so as to eliminate this problem ?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this?  I'm experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending upon your circumstances, adding

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

to the activity tag in the manifest may solve the issue.

Both worked in my case.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" is not a valid value according to the official docs. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: @MrMaffen That's weird, it's listed here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowSoftInputMode